# How do I split the string

Tags: perl, split

ALL,

I have a file which contains following string:

`VERIFYFAIL usbhd-sdb "There were 1 files with viruses detected. The device has been detached. Infections found: "`

And here is my code to get the results:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open( INFILE, "/home/me/scan_result" ) || die "Can't open file";
push( @lines, $_ ) while <INFILE>;
print @lines, "\n";
($result_string) = (split /"/, @lines)[1];
print $result_string, "\n";
close INFILE;
```

However, while the first print successfully prints the string from the file, the second print prints an empty line.

Basically I'm looking for a string between the quotes. But for some reason I'm failing to get it.

Could someone see my error?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

That code is treating the input as being **multiple** lines. To apply an operation across elements of an array, you need to use `map`:

```
my @result_strings = map {(split /"/, $_)[1]} @lines;
print join "\n", @result_strings; print "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 :** 
You can use regex match to get the string between double quotes. Learn about  "Pattern Memory" [here](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node90.html).

```
my $file = "/path/to/scan_result";
open (my $infile, "<", $file) or die "Can't open :$!";
while (<$infile>) {
    print $1."\n" if ($_ = /\"(.*)\"/);
}
```

**Method 2:** 
Similar to your code, split the string at double quotes and get the value at index 1 from the array after the split.

```
my $file = "/path/to/scan_result";
open (my $infile, "<", $file) or die "Can't open :$!";
while (<$infile>) {
    print [split /\"/, $_]->[1]."\n";
}
```

And, always use three argument form of [open](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html).